# Junit Test got error NestedServletException when try to excute Junit Test for RestApi DeleteById

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, dto, spring-test

`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed`

Get this exception error when try to execute Junit Test for restApi method to DeleteById

the problem that in Controller implements when i change return type of method from DeviceTO to device it works but i need to be returned as DeviceTO (DTO) so i faced this issue :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Please help me

this is the code for test class:

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class DeviceControllerFacadeTest {
    
    @Mock
    DeviceServiceImpl deviceServiceMock;
    @MockBean
    DeviceControllerFacadeImpl deviceControllerFacade = new DeviceControllerFacadeImpl();
    
    MockMvc mockMvc;


    /**
     * 
     */
    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(deviceControllerFacade)
                .build();

    }

    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */

    @After
    public void tearDown()
            throws Exception
    {
    }

    
    /**
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test
    public void DeleteDeviceById()
            throws Exception
    {
            mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                    .delete("/device/delete?id=336").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                              .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                              .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
     
    }
```

and this is the controller interface :

```
    @DeleteMapping("/delete")
    DeviceTO deleteDevice(@RequestParam("id") long id);
```

and this is for Controller implements class:

```
     @Override
     public DeviceTO  deleteDevice(long id)
    {
      

        try {

            begin();

            Device device = deviceService.getEntity(id);

            //deviceService.delete(device);
            DeviceTO deviceTO = new DeviceTO();
            deviceTO.mergeEntityToTransferObject(device);
            commit();
            return deviceTO;

        } catch (

        final Exception exception) {
            LOG.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
            throw  exception;

        } finally {
            cleanupTransaction();

        }
    }
```

Thank you for helping

I need this issue of exception will never appear again and the Test of method deleteById worked and return the device are deleted and the return type is DeviceTO not Device.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) --- "*i expect a solution to be working*" - I suggest [edit]ing and rephrasing this part of the post. Having expectations on a Q&A site where the community provides help for free is an attitude that is not well regarded around here.

Comment: i did edit it as you asked for

Comment: This NestedServletException is got deprecated since @Deprecated(since="6.0"), is there any replacement for this ? Its not required now ? I'm not finding any clue, any suggestions would be great.